# Passing values to vector as a member of a class in C++

Tags: c++, methods, chaining

I would like to pass values to a vector from the main function, where the vector is initialized as a member function of vectorEx class : 
Here's the code.

This is done in attempt to overloading "+" to add elements of vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class vectorEx
{
    public:
        vector<double> v(5);
        static const int m = 5;
};

int main()
{
    vectorEx a;
    cout << a.m << endl;
    (a.v).at(0) = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are :

```
vectorInsideClasses.cpp:9:20: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
vectorInsideClasses.cpp:9:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
vectorInsideClasses.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
vectorInsideClasses.cpp:22:7: error: ‘a.vectorEx::v’ does not have class type
```

Is this not like Method chaining in Java?

For example in Java: `System.out.println("Hello")`, which is the same as `(System.out).println("Hello")`

Comment: Can you tag the relevant language? Looks like C++ but I haven't been exposed to it enough to be certain.

Comment: I don't think `System.out.println` is method chaining, even in Java.  Namely, neither `System` nor `out` are methods.

Comment: @Pgram pay attention to the line number of the error messages... the problem is  at `vector<double> v(5);` , not the "chaining" !  The error on line 22 is a cascade from line 9 (since line 9 did not actually declare object `v`, the attempt to use `v` on line 22 gets an error). Typically, you fix the first error in the list of errors and then recompile to see what's left, unless you're experienced enough to recognize which are cascaded errors and which aren't.

Comment: Note that the preferred style is to overload `operator+=` as a member function which will push into `this->v`, and then provide `T operator+(T a, T const &b) { return a += b; }`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Except for containers, where we use boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't let you initialize non-static members in a class *quite* like that.  The official way is like this:

```
        vector<double> v = vector<double>(5);
```

Unfortunately, Microsoft Visual Studio does not yet support initializing non-static members in the body like this, so instead you have to use a constructor.

```
class vectorEx
{
    public:
        vector<double> v;
        static const int m = 5;

    vectorEx() //the default constructor 
        : v(5) //initialize the non-static member
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `v(m)` in the initializer list, or is the int just an example of an item you can initialize in the declaration and the 5 is just coincidence?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I didn't see anything in the question to suggest that `m` is the size of `v` other than the values used.  It's possible that's what the OP intended.  Nevertheless, I realized a mistake in my answer (and 0x499602D2's).

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that in the op.  Sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Yes, Mooing Duck is right, I just left that part about m. It has got nothing to do with vector size.

Answer (score 1):

Direct-initialization of a data member is not possible within the class. The compiler will confuse the parenthesis as a function declaration. If your compiler supports C++11, you can initialize this way:

```c++
vector<double> v = std::vector<double>(5);
```

Alternstively, if you can't use C++11 then you can initialize through the constructor:

```c++
vectorEx() : v(5) { }
```

Comment: I just remembered that `vector<double>(5)` and `vector<double>{5}` are very very different things...

Comment: @MooingDuck You are right. `vector<double>(5)` this means that the vector has five elements, each element's value is `0.0`, but `vector<double>{5}` means that the vector has only one element, the element's value is `5`.